# Parse "parse new " not working

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have just downloaded the ParseConsole.exe  run it. I already have an app in my account in parse.com. The problem is that when I run the command "parse new" in the ParseConsole and log in the ParseConsole only shows me "1: results" instead os my app to choose. What should I do? [Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSR4J.png)

Comment: Can you provide more details like screen shot?

Comment: Here is an image os what happens: http://i.stack.imgur.com/xSR4J.png

Comment: For me the issue was that what the docs said, to provide the project name in the cmd line .. like so `parse new MyCloudCode` .. was not working .  Using the link below to parse.com/docs .. there they show to just call it as `parse new` and then select the project name afterward using the prompts in the parse command tool interface

Answer (score 2):

I just came across this and just updated to the latest Parse CLI and it resolved my issue.

https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#command-line-updating

Comment: cool, thanks for the link.  I especially found this section helpful for "Setting up your App" https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#command-line-setting-up-your-app